# Helping my dog through a breakup

Tags: dogs

My girlfriend and I have been having some troubles lately, and I'm pretty sure we're going to break up in the next month. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to best help my dog through the separation?

My dog is 8, but I've only had her for about 8 months. My dog is used to my girlfriend staying most nights a week at my place and usually seems to be in a worse mood for at least day after my gf leaves to stay at her place.

My girlfriend has basically been her second parent since the beginning and is definitely her favorite of the 2 of us. I'm really worried about how she'll adjust to having just me around.

Any suggestions on easing the transition?

Comment: Is it an option for your girlfriend to keep the dog?

Comment: @mhwombat I don't think that would solve anything, then the dog would just be missing the op.

Comment: @MattS. but it would miss the OP less than it would miss his girlfriend, according to the OPs own facts?

Comment: A possible suggestion is to get a second pet, can you update your questions to include if this a possibility?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Your dog will just think she left to go back to her place and would not care if she doesn't come back. As long as you are in an upbeat mood, there is nothing to worry about

Comment: @mhwmobat My gf can't keep the dog because her place doesn't allow dogs over 25lbs...also, i want to keep my dog. She might enjoy playing with my girlfriend more...but she definitely respects me more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Distraction** : I live with my sister and brother-in-law and our two dogs. Both of them are attached more to them. Whenever they go out-station for longer time i have similar problem but the option i choose is distraction.

Make them busy, making their walk longer, spend more time with them, make their iteration with neighbouring dogs and human more. Playing with them, for the rest time, i sit with them with-outing even playing too (even presence also works) and help me in my laptop etc work too.

**Company:** If its not possible to give company by your own self, then you can seek help from other friend and helful neighbour too. Else have a **second pet** but it will bring more responsibility too during initial stage.

Comment: thanks. i don't know that a second pet would be manageable right now...but I'll definitely try to increase the amount of time she's socializing, walking and playing.

Answer (score 2):

Reminder: the dog doesn't know the difference between a breakup and one of you going on a long business trip. They're going to react more to the humans' moods than to anything else.